# Losing my session state : (x(1)) in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, session-state

I developped an ASP.Net MVC3 application that works really well.

Sometimes though, the session state just stop functionning as it should do : I get a (X(1)) in my URLS and have to log in again after each link click.

> Example : I log in, I'm redirected to the home page.
>   Then I click one link, the link is just as usual, except there is a (X(1)) in the middle.

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479315.aspx) at msdn, this behavior is normal when a device does not support cookies... As I'm using Google Chrome 21 or IE 10, I think it's not the case

My application worked Yesterday.

Details :

- it is hosted in Windows Azure Cloud Service,
- my form Authentication is configured as : cookieless="AutoDetect"
- I'm using the Standard Providers for session and membership.

Any clue please?

Comment: How many instances are you using? Did you change the number of instances since yesterday?

Comment: Hi, forgot to tell : I have one instance only. It did not change since weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `cookieless="AutoDetect"` with `cookieless="UseCookies"`